# Netbeans Database service empty list

Tags: database, netbeans, service

I have Java 86/x64. Install Neatbeans 7.0. Look in to the tab Service->Database and see, that list is empty. Hoow fix it to add new DB ?

screenshot: http://s49.radikal.ru/i125/1105/1f/7f9123eb0018.jpg

Comment: You should at the very least have a Drivers folder inside your Database folder. The DB drivers should come with your NetBeans installation.  I suspect an installation error and suggest to try again.

Comment: thanks you, i found that this is bug statistics.netbeans.org/exceptions/exception.do?id=509413

Comment: waw...!! I encountered the same simptompt while using Netbeans 6.9.1..... OMG

Answer (score 1):

Try right click on the node and choose "New connection". You should also be able to register a MySQL server from the context menu.

Comment: thanks you, i found that this is bug http://statistics.netbeans.org/exceptions/exception.do?id=509413